# Stacky JSON error

Tags: support, c#, json, stacky

I'm trying to use Stacky to grab a question from Stackoverflow, however I always an error. The error thrown is:

`JsonReaderException was unhandled - 
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Line 1, position 1.`

My code is:

```
var stackClient = new StackyClient("0.9", "<my appid>", Sites.StackOverflow, new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());
Question q = stackClient.GetQuestion(4619829);
```

Anyone any idea?

I've tried referencing both the Newtonsoft.Json assembly that came bundled with the binary download of Stacky and the version in the dependencies folder in the most up to date source version too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but I bet "0.9" should be "1.0" in your code.

The API version is currently 1.0, 0.9 was a beta version which has long since been deprecated.

Comment: This was the problem, I was using a tutorial that must have been written long ago!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var stackClient = new StackyClient("1.0", "<my appid>", Sites.StackOverflow, new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());
```